# Cannot export excel file from dataTable by using epplus in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have found lots of examples and tutorials about how to export a `DataTable` as Excel by using epplus, but I cannot find a direct way to do it. Therefore I tried  the following code..

my dataTable:

```
===============================
d1    | d2    |  d3
===============================
aa1   | bb1   | cc1
aa2   | bb2   | cc2
aa3   | bb3   | cc3
aa4   | bb4   | cc4
```

script:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;

//........
    protected viod exportToExcel (dataTable dt)
    {
        try
        {

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Logs.xlsx", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
               ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Logs");
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);                 
                var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                pck.SaveAs(ms);
                ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);                          
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug("error: " + ex.Message);//catch nothing
        }

    }
```

It returns a server error and no any exception is caught, so I have no idea what error happens..

However, no error occurs when I remove the

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
```

section in above code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just quick skim comments... I assume your return type is not supposed to be `void` and not `viod` though you must have that right in your code to compile. Also I'm not sure if it's the cause of your problem but your first parameter in LoadFromDataTable needs to be the variable `dt` not the type `dataTable`. Doesn't seem like that would compile either though. Isn't C# case sensitive and thus needs `dataTable` to have a capital D?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff i don't know what is the meaning of return type( i am very new to  C#). i just want to provide a feature that when user clicks a download button, then the data table will be downloaded as excel format to their computer. Also, i edited  my code

Answer (score 0):

Best way to export to excel from server, convert the data table to HtmlTextWriter.
In the 
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=file.xls");

Response.ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel";
and finally

Response.Output.Write(htmltexwriter)

Comment: i want to styling the excel file, so epplus should be a better choice.